# Pass variable to SqlDataSource.SelectParameter, then pass query result to new string ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader, sqldatasource

I have the following SqlDataSource defined as a DataReader, with a blank Default Value:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="getPhoneNumber" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MobileLeasesConnectionString %>" DataSourceMode="DataReader" SelectCommand="SELECT Phone FROM MobileLeases WHERE OwnerName = @techName">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="techName" Type="string" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have a button click event that grabs the value of a Form field at the time the button is clicked, and puts it in `string techName`...

```
protected void submitter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    //grab the value of ftechName at the time the button is clicked...        
    string techName = Request.Form["ftechName"]; //grab the techs name}
```

I need to pass the value of `techName` to getPhoneNumber... and return the single result to a new string, call it string `phoneNum`.

I have tried several things and just need to be advised from scratch, because it is all a blur now.

Big picture, it should look like this...

```
protected void submitter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    //grab the value of ftechName at the time the button is clicked...        
    string techName = Request.Form["ftechName"]; //grab the techs name}

    //run select command with techName as the SELECT parameter...
    getPhoneNumber > Select Phone WHERE OwnerName = techName
    string phoneNum = result of getPhoneNumber query
```

What is the best method for passing `techName` and getting the result into `phoneNum`?

Thank you so much for any advice.

Comment: I voted you up, but it looks like someone else voted this down. I hate it when people downvote someone's work without even having the balls to comment why.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, because I don't use much ASP.NET:

```
getPhoneNumber.SelectParameters.Add("@techName", System.Data.DbType.String, techName);
```

** UPDATE: **

Here is some code I wrote that works without that `asp:SqlDataSource` control:

```
protected void Submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var techName = ftechName.Text.Trim();
    // assuming your phone number control on your ASP.NET page is "rPhonenumber"
    rPhonenumber.Text = GetPhoneNumber(techName);
}

private const String SQL_CONNECTION = "ConnectionStrings:MobileLeasesConnectionString";

private String GetPhoneNumber(String techName)
{
    var result = String.Empty;
    using (var con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(SQL_CONNECTION))
    {
        // Give it your SQL command
        var sql = "SELECT Phone FROM MobileLeases WHERE OwnerName = @techName";
        // Create an SqlCommand instance
        var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con);
        // Supply it with your parameter (data type and size should match whatever the value is for [MobileLeases].[OwnerName] in SQL)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@techName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = techName;
        // Don't forget to open the connection!
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        // String.Format handles the case of the SELECT command returning NULL - converting that to an empty string
        result = String.Format("{0}", cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        // optionally, you can close the connection, but the 'using' statement should take care of that.
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
    // return your results
    return result;
}
```

Much simpler to understand what's going on, in my opinion.

Comment: This link might help: [MSDN - SqlDataSource Example C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1kdt8w2.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks, but I feel like this is one line out of many that will be needed. This may pass the parameter but does it use the SQL connection, create the new string for phoneNum, etc...

Comment: I had seen this article, and many others, and still cannot get this to work.

Comment: You need `runat="server"` for both the `fTechName` TextBox and the `submitter` Button. Double clicking the Button in the designer needs to take you to the `submitter_Click` method in your code.

Comment: The `submitter` button does run on the server. It calls `submitter_Click` in the code behind and works fine. `fTechName` is a Select Control whose options are all populated on the client side, in the browser.

Comment: I'm not sure if a **SqlDataSource** control is the best for populating a text box. The examples I see all point to it being used in ListViews or Grids. Can I write in another way? (edit the Answer above)

Comment: The SqlDataSource does not populate the text box. I am trying to pass the value from the Select Control, at the time the submitter button is clicked, to the SqlDataSource as a parameter. Once that value is passed and the query runs, I want to capture that result in another variable, phoneNum. I hope that is more clear. Thanks!

Comment: I will try your code above tomorrow and report back!

Comment: I'm just not sure how you would use an **SqlDataSource** control to supply data to an **asp:TextBox**, since it does not have a DataSource setting. You might have to add a ListBox with `Visible = false` to connect the SqlDataSource to. Then, after you click Submit, you would take the first result from ListBox (there should be only 1 or 0) and write that to your Phone Number control. (???)

Comment: I am reviewing your work this morning, and it does make sense. I come from more experience with Powershell, Javascript, not much .net or C#. What stands out here is that I do not have a control on the page for `phoneNum`. I wanted to create the `phoneNum` string/variable when `submitter` is clicked, then pass the result from my SQL query directly to it, then re-use it, then trash it for the next click. The result has to be bound to a control in .net? Thank you!